# Modify an array of elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an application where users can add their data in a form with 2 fields. They can add as many fields as they want.

```
const Demo = () => {
  const onFinish = values => {
    console.log("Received values of form:", values);
  };
  const firstDefaultOpen = {
    name: 0,
    key: 0,
    isListField: true,
    fieldKey: 0
  };
  const testHandler = a => {
    console.log("result", a.concat(firstDefaultOpen));
    return a.concat(firstDefaultOpen);
  };
  return (
    <Form name="dynamic_form_nest_item" onFinish={onFinish} autoComplete="off">
      <Form.List name="users">
        {(fields, { add, remove }) => {
          return (
            <div>
              {testHandler(fields).map(field => (
                <Space
                  key={field.key}
                  style={{ display: "flex", marginBottom: 8 }}
                  align="start"
                >
                  <Form.Item
                    {...field}
                    name={[field.name, "first"]}
                    fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "first"]}
                    rules={[{ required: true, message: "Missing first name" }]}
                  >
                    <Input placeholder="First Name" />
                  </Form.Item>
                  <Form.Item
                    {...field}
                    name={[field.name, "last"]}
                    fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "last"]}
                    rules={[{ required: true, message: "Missing last name" }]}
                  >
                    <Input placeholder="Last Name" />
                  </Form.Item>

                  <MinusCircleOutlined
                    onClick={() => {
                      remove(field.name);
                    }}
                  />
                </Space>
              ))}

              <Form.Item>
                <Button
                  type="dashed"
                  onClick={() => {
                    add();
                  }}
                  block
                >
                  <PlusOutlined /> Add field
                </Button>
              </Form.Item>
            </div>
          );
        }}
      </Form.List>

      <Form.Item>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};
```

My target is to set a default pair of inputs as opened. Now you can see when you open the application that `first name` and `last name` inputs are open as default. This i made with:

```
 const firstDefaultOpen = {
    name: 0,
    key: 0,
    isListField: true,
    fieldKey: 0
  };
  const testHandler = a => {
    console.log("result", a.concat(firstDefaultOpen));
    return a.concat(firstDefaultOpen);
  };
```

and here i map() the new array:

```
 {testHandler(fields).map(field => (...
```

The issue is when i click on `Add field` button, because there when i try to write something in one input also the same text appears on the another. This is happening because when i click on `Add field` button you can see in the `console.log("result", a.concat(firstDefaultOpen));`, that 2 objects are with the same  values like:

```
[Object, Object]
0: Object
name: 0
key: 0
isListField: true
fieldKey: 0
1: Object
name: 0
key: 0
isListField: true
fieldKey: 0
```

Question: How to set the first object with all values 0, and the next values to be higher, and to get something like?:

```
[Object, Object]
0: Object
name: 0
key: 0
isListField: true
fieldKey: 0
1: Object
name: 1
key: 1
isListField: true
fieldKey: 1
2: Object
name: 2
key: 2
isListField: true
fieldKey: 2
...
```

demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-star-nu5ld?file=/index.js:783-819

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by just simply changing your `firstDefaultOption` from variable to function like this

```
    function firstDefaultOption(optionVal){
        return {
         name: optionVal,
         key: optionVal,
         isListField: optionVal,
         fieldKey: optionVal
     }
   }
```

and then changing your test handler like this

```
    const testHandler = a => {
    console.log("A",a)
    console.log("result", a.concat(firstDefaultOption(a.length)));
    return a.concat(firstDefaultOption(a.length));
  };
```

Comment: i like your solution, i implemented in one of my application and when i upload an image, bellow appears suddenly another pair of inputs. Without your implementation it does not appears, do you see any issues? https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-star-nu5ld?file=/index.js  . I know that maybe this is additional question , but could you take a look please? It will be great if you will help,thanks.

Comment: what do you think about the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a messy solution but it works... Comments added throughout

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Form, Input, Button, Space } from "antd";
import { MinusCircleOutlined, PlusOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";

const Demo = () => {
  const onFinish = values => {
    console.log("Received values of form:", values);
  };
  const firstDefaultOpen = {
    //Set default to null
    name: null,
    key: null,
    isListField: true,
    fieldKey: null
  };
  const testHandler = a => {
    //Check for null and set first to 0
    if(firstDefaultOpen.name == null){
      firstDefaultOpen.name = 0;
      firstDefaultOpen.key = 0;
      firstDefaultOpen.fieldKey = 0;
    }
    //If not null.. then add 1 to each object item to make each unique
    else{
      firstDefaultOpen.name = firstDefaultOpen.name +1;
      firstDefaultOpen.key = firstDefaultOpen.key +1;
      firstDefaultOpen.fieldKey = firstDefaultOpen.fieldKey +1;
    }
    
    console.log("result", a.concat(firstDefaultOpen));
    return a.concat(firstDefaultOpen);
  };
  return (
    <Form name="dynamic_form_nest_item" onFinish={onFinish} autoComplete="off">
      <Form.List name="users">
        {(fields, { add, remove }) => {
          return (
            <div>
              {testHandler(fields).map(field => (
                <Space
                  key={field.key}
                  style={{ display: "flex", marginBottom: 8 }}
                  align="start"
                >
                  <Form.Item
                    {...field}
                    name={[field.name, "first"]}
                    fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "first"]}
                    rules={[{ required: true, message: "Missing first name" }]}
                  >
                    <Input placeholder="First Name" />
                  </Form.Item>
                  <Form.Item
                    {...field}
                    name={[field.name, "last"]}
                    fieldKey={[field.fieldKey, "last"]}
                    rules={[{ required: true, message: "Missing last name" }]}
                  >
                    <Input placeholder="Last Name" />
                  </Form.Item>

                  <MinusCircleOutlined
                    onClick={() => {
                      remove(field.name);
                    }}
                  />
                </Space>
              ))}

              <Form.Item>
                <Button
                  type="dashed"
                  onClick={() => {
                    add();
                  }}
                  block
                >
                  <PlusOutlined /> Add field
                </Button>
              </Form.Item>
            </div>
          );
        }}
      </Form.List>

      <Form.Item>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Demo />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Comment: it does not work when i add many subfields. The text from fields is copied  and in another input.

Comment: Everything seems fine on my end.. unless I'm reading your question wrong? Link------>https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-star-nu5ld?file=/index.js

Comment: the issue is: when i fill the inputs with text and when i add the image, bellow appears another pair of inputs, but they should not appear.

Answer (score 0):

You could declare the `defaultOpen` object with the `let` keyword and invoke an "update" function whenever you're ready to display an updated version, like:

```js
let defaultOpen = getFirstDefaultOpen();
log(defaultOpen);

updateDefaultOpen(defaultOpen);
log(defaultOpen);

updateDefaultOpen(defaultOpen);
log(defaultOpen);

function updateDefaultOpen(currentState){
  currentState.name++;
  currentState.key++;
  currentState.fieldKey++;
}
function getFirstDefaultOpen(){
  return {
    name: 0,
    key: 0,
    isListField: true,
    fieldKey: 0
  }
}
function log(currentState){
  const output = Object.keys(currentState).reduce((str, key)=>{
    str += `${key}:${currentState[key]}, `;
    return str;
  },"");
  console.log(`{ ${output}}`);
}
```